# SQL Server Function - CTE defined but not used

Tags: sql-server, function, common-table-expression

I am trying to create function in SQL Server that returns months between range of dates passed to function. Below is my current script -

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_get_date_range]  ( 
@startDate datetime,
@endDate datetime,
@frequency varchar(20)
)
RETURNS  
@dateRanges TABLE 
(
  report_date datetime
)
AS
BEGIN 

    WITH DateRange (report_date) AS
    (   

        SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY object_id) FROM sys.all_objects)
        SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@StartDate)+report_date,0) 

    ) AS report_date    
    insert into @dateRanges (report_date)
    Select report_date FROM DateRange
    WHERE report_date <= DATEDIFF(month, @StartDate, @EndDate)+1


RETURN 

END
```

But when I try to create these function, I get below error -

> Common table expression defined but not used.

I have tried different approach but it doesn't work. Any pointers in right direction would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my TVF used for dynamic datetime ranges.

Similar to your approach, but I do have the DATEPART as a parameter as well as the increment.

**Example - Month Increment 1:**

```
Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Range-Date]('2016-01-01','2017-01-01','MM',1)
```

**Returns**

[image]

**Example - Minute Increment 15:**

```
Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Range-Date]('2017-01-01','2017-01-02','MI',15)
```

**Returns**

[image]

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Range-Date] (@R1 datetime,@R2 datetime,@Part varchar(10),@Incr int)
Returns Table
Return (
    with cte0(M)   As (Select 1+Case @Part When 'YY' then DateDiff(YY,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'QQ' then DateDiff(QQ,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MM' then DateDiff(MM,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'WK' then DateDiff(WK,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'DD' then DateDiff(DD,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'HH' then DateDiff(HH,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MI' then DateDiff(MI,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'SS' then DateDiff(SS,@R1,@R2)/@Incr End),
         cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
         cte2(N)   As (Select Top (Select M from cte0) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From cte1 a, cte1 b, cte1 c, cte1 d, cte1 e, cte1 f, cte1 g, cte1 h ),
         cte3(N,D) As (Select 0,@R1 Union All Select N,Case @Part When 'YY' then DateAdd(YY, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'QQ' then DateAdd(QQ, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MM' then DateAdd(MM, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'WK' then DateAdd(WK, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'DD' then DateAdd(DD, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'HH' then DateAdd(HH, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MI' then DateAdd(MI, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'SS' then DateAdd(SS, N*@Incr, @R1) End From cte2 )

    Select RetSeq = N+1
          ,RetVal = D 
     From  cte3,cte0 
     Where D<=@R2
)
/*
Max 100 million observations -- Date Parts YY QQ MM WK DD HH MI SS
Syntax:
Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','YY',1) 
Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Range-Date]('2016-01-01','2017-01-01','MM',1) 
*/
```

> **EDIT - As Requested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Range-Date-Span] (@R1 datetime,@R2 datetime,@Part varchar(10),@Incr int)
Returns Table
Return (
    with cte0(M)   As (Select 1+Case @Part When 'YY' then DateDiff(YY,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'QQ' then DateDiff(QQ,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MM' then DateDiff(MM,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'WK' then DateDiff(WK,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'DD' then DateDiff(DD,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'HH' then DateDiff(HH,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MI' then DateDiff(MI,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'SS' then DateDiff(SS,@R1,@R2)/@Incr End),
         cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
         cte2(N)   As (Select Top (Select M from cte0) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From cte1 a,cte1 b,cte1 c,cte1 d,cte1 e,cte1 f,cte1 g,cte1 h ),
         cte3(N,D) As (Select 0,@R1 Union All Select N,Case @Part When 'YY' then DateAdd(YY,N*@Incr,@R1) When 'QQ' then DateAdd(QQ,N*@Incr,@R1) When 'MM' then DateAdd(MM,N*@Incr,@R1) When 'WK' then DateAdd(WK,N*@Incr,@R1) When 'DD' then DateAdd(DD,N*@Incr,@R1) When 'HH' then DateAdd(HH,N*@Incr,@R1) When 'MI' then DateAdd(MI,N*@Incr,@R1) When 'SS' then DateAdd(SS,N*@Incr,@R1) End From cte2 )

    Select RetSeq  = N+1
          ,RetVal1 = D
          ,RetVal2 = LEAD(D,1,@R2) over (Order By D)
    From   cte3,cte0 
    Where  N<cte0.M-1
)
--Max 100 million observations -- Date Parts YY QQ MM WK DD HH MI SS
--Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Range-Date-Span]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','YY',1)
```

**Returns something like this**

[image]

> **Edit 2 - For 2008**

```
;with cte as (
    Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Range-Date]('2016-01-01','2017-01-01','MM',1) 
)
Select DateR1 = A.RetVal
      ,DateR2 = B.NxtDate
 From cte A
 Cross Apply (Select NxtDate=min(RetVal) from cte where RetVal > A.RetVal ) B
 Where B.NxtDate is not null
```

**Returns**

[image]

Comment: Wow. That's one hack of code. This function provides most of things that I planned to implement. I would appreciate if you can show me how can one return start date and end date of the range instead of one start date column. If that's not possible, how can I return end date  like '2017-01-31 23:59:59' instead '2017-01-01'

Comment: @indusBull See  EDIT - I added a second function which does Ranges

Comment: @indusBull I should add that the RetVal2 is the same as the next RetVal1.  This is intetional because I select where value >=RetVal1 and value <RetVal2

Comment: Unfortunately, I only have SQL Server 2008 R2 which doesn't support LEAD()    :-(    Thanks for the updated code though.

Comment: @indusBull Since 2008, with the first solution, you could use a CROSS APPLY to select min date which is > than the record's date

Comment: @indusBull See EDIT for 2008

Answer (score 1):

It is not allowed that CTE is not followed by `SELECT` statement, cite from MS:

> •A CTE must be followed by a single SELECT statement. INSERT, UPDATE,
>   DELETE, and MERGE statements are not supported.

**UPDATE**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_get_date_range]  ( 
@startDate datetime,
@endDate datetime,
@frequency varchar(20)
)
RETURNS  
@dateRanges TABLE 
(
  report_date datetime
)
AS
BEGIN 

    WITH DateRange (report_date) AS
    (   

        SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY object_id) FROM sys.all_objects)
        SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@StartDate)+report_date,0) 

    ) AS report_date    

    Select * FROM DateRange 
    INTO #temp_table
    WHERE report_date <= DATEDIFF(month, @StartDate, @EndDate)+1

    insert into @dateRanges (report_date)
    select * from #temp_table

    drop table #temp_table

    RETURN 

    END
```

Comment: how do I do temp or derived table as you mentioned?

Comment: @indusBull, you can create another temp table using `select into`, then insert into your table variable from that temp table, check my update

Answer (score 1):

This is a variant that's similar to John's function...

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.tfn_BuildDateRanges
(
    @startDate DATETIME,
    @endDate DATETIME,
    @dateInterval VARCHAR(20),
    @interval INT
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
    WITH 
        cte_n1 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) n (n)), 
        cte_n2 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte_n1 a CROSS JOIN cte_n1 b),
        cte_n3 (n) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte_n2 a CROSS JOIN cte_n2 b),
        cte_Calendar AS (
            SELECT TOP ((CASE
                            WHEN @dateInterval IN ('year', 'yy', 'yyyy')    THEN DATEDIFF(year,         @startDate, @endDate)
                            WHEN @dateInterval IN ('quarter', 'qq', 'q')    THEN DATEDIFF(quarter,      @startDate, @endDate)
                            WHEN @dateInterval IN ('month', 'mm', 'm')      THEN DATEDIFF(month,        @startDate, @endDate)
                            WHEN @dateInterval IN ('week    wk, ww')        THEN DATEDIFF(week,         @startDate, @endDate)
                            WHEN @dateInterval IN ('day', 'dd', 'd')        THEN DATEDIFF(day,          @startDate, @endDate)
                            WHEN @dateInterval IN ('hour', 'hh')            THEN DATEDIFF(hour,         @startDate, @endDate)
                            WHEN @dateInterval IN ('minute', 'mi', 'n')     THEN DATEDIFF(minute,       @startDate, @endDate)
                            WHEN @dateInterval IN ('second', 'ss', 's')     THEN DATEDIFF(second,       @startDate, @endDate)
                        END / @interval + 1))
                BegOfRange = CASE
                        WHEN @dateInterval IN ('year', 'yy', 'yyyy')    THEN DATEADD(year,          (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1) * @interval, @startDate)
                        WHEN @dateInterval IN ('quarter', 'qq', 'q')    THEN DATEADD(quarter,       (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1) * @interval, @startDate)
                        WHEN @dateInterval IN ('month', 'mm', 'm')      THEN DATEADD(month,         (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1) * @interval, @startDate)
                        WHEN @dateInterval IN ('week    wk, ww')        THEN DATEADD(week,          (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1) * @interval, @startDate)
                        WHEN @dateInterval IN ('day', 'dd', 'd')        THEN DATEADD(day,           (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1) * @interval, @startDate)
                        WHEN @dateInterval IN ('hour', 'hh')            THEN DATEADD(hour,          (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1) * @interval, @startDate)
                        WHEN @dateInterval IN ('minute', 'mi', 'n')     THEN DATEADD(minute,        (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1) * @interval, @startDate)
                        WHEN @dateInterval IN ('second', 'ss', 's')     THEN DATEADD(second,        (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1) * @interval, @startDate)
                    END,
            EndOfRange = CASE
                        WHEN @dateInterval IN ('year', 'yy', 'yyyy')    THEN DATEADD(year,          (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))     ) * @interval, @startDate)
                        WHEN @dateInterval IN ('quarter', 'qq', 'q')    THEN DATEADD(quarter,       (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))     ) * @interval, @startDate)
                        WHEN @dateInterval IN ('month', 'mm', 'm')      THEN DATEADD(month,         (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))     ) * @interval, @startDate)
                        WHEN @dateInterval IN ('week    wk, ww')        THEN DATEADD(week,          (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))     ) * @interval, @startDate)
                        WHEN @dateInterval IN ('day', 'dd', 'd')        THEN DATEADD(day,           (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))     ) * @interval, @startDate)
                        WHEN @dateInterval IN ('hour', 'hh')            THEN DATEADD(hour,          (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))     ) * @interval, @startDate)
                        WHEN @dateInterval IN ('minute', 'mi', 'n')     THEN DATEADD(minute,        (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))     ) * @interval, @startDate)
                        WHEN @dateInterval IN ('second', 'ss', 's')     THEN DATEADD(second,        (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))     ) * @interval, @startDate)
                    END
        FROM 
            cte_n3 a CROSS JOIN cte_n3 b
        )
SELECT 
    c.BegOfRange, 
    c.EndOfRange
FROM
    cte_Calendar c;
GO
```

Comment: Thank you. How can I change this code to one return start date and end date of the range instead of one start date column. If that's not possible, how can I return end date like '2017-01-31 23:59:59' instead '2017-01-01'

Comment: I mistakenly left my testing values in the function definition. I've edited the answer to remove them... As to your question, I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Checkout John's edit on what I was asking. Thanks for help.